Is it possible to get the angle of rotation of the text area via PaddleOCR?
PaddleOCR can correctly recognize 90, 180 and even 270 degree rotated text in a mode use_angle_cls=True, but it doesnt provide any information about the angle of rotation in a result.As a result, area with a text, cropped by provided coordinates usually has incorrect orientation.
Can i get the information about the angle of rotation of the text area somehow to get correctly orientated area witht text ?
Primal image example
Cropped area with text with incorrect orientation
Cropped area with text with incorrect orientation

Yes, it is possible, because PaddleOCR has variables with necessary information in its code.Answer is here:
https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/discussions/13264
